# Javascript syntax and behaviour in MS Dynamics

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a form which I want to build some simple validation for, but I cannot seem to get it working correctly.  The option set has about 10 choices, but I only want to create some validation for some of them.  For example, if you are a certain race, a "specify" textbox will appear on the dynamics form to allow you to enter data, but the box will no appear if you make certain selections from the optionset.  I hope I've explained that clearly.

Currently, the below code works as  follows:

The other box is not visible on form load, when you make a selection from the optionset dropdown, it appears on the form and allows you to enter data.  However, it should only appear if a certain choice is selected.  When an incorrect choice is made, it should clear and become invisible again.  At the moment, it stays visible and text the stays in the field. By default, the optionset has no assigned value on formload.

Code below, I think it must be my if statement is incorrect somehow.

```
function Example_Other() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_choiceoptionset").getValue();
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_choiceoptionset").getValue() == "White, Other
 (specify)" || "Asian, Other (specify)" ||
        "African, Other (specify)" || "Mixed, any other (specify)" || "Other ethnic group (specify)") {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_othertextbox").setVisible(true);
    } else {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_othertextbox").setVisible(false);
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_othertextbox").setValue(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the number value of the options, NOT the string assigned value...  It's not ideal (as values could need changing over time) But it gives the desired functionality.

Example:

```
var myValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_choiceexample").getValue();
 if (myValue == 778300002 || 
myValue == 778300006 || 
myValue == 778300009 || 
myValue == 778300014 || 
myValue == 778300015)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

`if` statement works in a different way. You have to provide a boolean expression, so if you want to perform a check like this you have to do something like:

```
var myValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_choiceoptionset").getValue()
if (myValue == "White, Other (specify)"
    || myValue == "Asian, Other (specify)"
    || myValue == "African, Other (specify)"
    || myValue == "Mixed, any other (specify)"
    || myValue == "Other ethnic group (specify)")
{
    //Your code here
} else {
    //Other code here
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Like java.  I completely forgot about this syntax.  Perfect, that's exactly what is wrong.  Thank you. :)

Comment: Hmmm... Doesn't see to work at all anymore.  I wonder if ' and " have different affect? The original behaviour is even gone now.

Comment: What's the content of the attribute?

Comment: ' and " seem to be equivalent.  So that's not the issue. The attributes are string values stored in an option-set. (dropdown menu in dynamics 2011) There is maybe ten, but only the 5 mentioned in the code sample above need to generate a "other" textbox.